# Swap HTML <option> values using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I've tried a range of methods to try and swap two options and none worked.

I want the first option of `select` to swap with first option of `select1`

Is anyone able to provide an example of how to deal with this swap?

Here is the JavaScript I have tried:

```js
$('#swap').click(function() {
  var v1 = $('#select').val(),
    v2 = $('#select1').val();
  $('#select').val(v2);
  $('#select1').val(v1);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="search-tour__converter">
  <form action="#" class="search-tour__form flex">
    <div class="search-tour__form_left-side">
      <input type="number" id="amount" value="1" class="search-tour__input">
      <div class="search-tour__drop-down">
        <select id="select" class="main-dropdown">
          <option value="EUR">EUR</option>
          <option value="EUR">EUR</option>
          <option value="USD">USD</option>
          <option value="UAH">UAH</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <button class="search-tour__btn" value="swap" id="swap" type="button">Swap
                </button>
    <div class="search-tour__form_right-side">
      <div class="search-tour__drop-down">
        <select id="select1" class="main-dropdown">
          <option value="UAH">UAH</option>
          <option value="UAH">UAH</option>
          <option value="USD">USD</option>
          <option value="EUR">EUR</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <input type="number" id="result" value="31.37" class="search-tour__input">
    </div>
    <input type="button" class="titles-block__btn" value="Конвертировать" onclick="calculate();">
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Where is your javascript? What do you mean swap 2 options? You need to provide a little more detail.

Comment: What doesn't work about it?

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms when I press button nothing happens

Comment: Works for me in JSFiddle...error seems non-reproducable

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms in jsfiddle it doesnt work for me..

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms https://jsfiddle.net/edsmv6uz/

Comment: Your example works fine

Comment: @JohnMozley it works for me in your StackSnippet above. when you say "doesn't work", what exactly do you mean? Are you getting an error of some kind? Have you checked the console?

Comment: @JohnMozley Maybe note that in your JSFiddle link, jQuery isn't selected as a library. If you select that, it works fine (the option values swap).

Comment: @ADyson I mean that this doesnt swap

Comment: @JohnMozley yes but what's _not_ happening is less important than what _is_ happening? Did you press F12, open your developer tools and look at the Console? If, as Daan says, jQuery is missing from your fiddle setup then you would definitely have an error in there which should give you a clue about the situation.

Comment: @JohnMozley You didn't enable jQuery in the dropdown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to do the following?

```js
$('#swap').click(function()
{
    var v1 = $('#select option:first-child');
    var v2 = $('#select1 option:first-child');
    

    var temp1 = v1.html();
    var temp2 = v2.html();

    v2.html(temp1);
    v1.html(temp2);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="search-tour__converter">
        <form action="#" class="search-tour__form flex">
            <div class="search-tour__form_left-side">
                <input type="number" id="amount" value="1" class="search-tour__input">
                <div class="search-tour__drop-down">
                    <select id="select" class="main-dropdown">
                        <option value="EUR">EUR</option>
                        <option value="USD">USD</option>
                        <option value="UAH">UAH</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <button class="search-tour__btn" value="swap" id="swap" type="button">Swap
            </button>
            <div class="search-tour__form_right-side">
                <div class="search-tour__drop-down">
                    <select id="select1" class="main-dropdown">
                        <option value="UAH">UAH</option>
                        <option value="USD">USD</option>
                        <option value="EUR">EUR</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <input type="number" id="result" value="31.37" class="search-tour__input">
            </div>
            <input type="button" class="titles-block__btn" value="Конвертировать" onclick="calculate();">
        </form>
    </div>
```